# reading dates using python read_csv with seperator / or - and years less than 1968

Tags: python, csv, date

I have twoissues regarding reading dates using read_csv in python

1. How to read dates that have mixed format ? The dates are in the form dd/mm/yy , dd-mm-yy , dd/mm/yyyy or dd-mm-yyyy
2. there are some dates in the years lesser than or equal to 1968. How to preserve the century information so that date comparisions can be performed correctly.

```
df = pd.read_csv('train.csv',dayfirst=True,parse_dates=['DoB','DisDt'])
```

I have also tried using date_parser

```
dtpse = lambda x:pd.datetime.strptime(x,'%d/%m/%y')
df = pd.read_csv('train.csv',dayfirst=True,parse_dates=['DoB','DisDt'],date_parser=dtpse)
```

The dates are in the form given below in the csv file

```
01/01/2008
01/01/74
12-04-2004
12-04-1968
01/06/1978
```

I am trying to use python read_csv to get the results shown below

**Expected Results**

```
01-01-2008
01-01-74
12-04-2004
12-04-1968
01-06-1978
```

The main aim is to store the century information so that while subtracting dates the correct difference is calculated .

Comment: Do you just want to replace the signs because then you could use the replace function: date.replace("/", "-")

Comment: Otherwise you to sort it you could then split it and append an 19 to every date that has only 2 digits

Comment: @SeanSdahl The basic objective is to find the difference between those two dates

Comment: Two dates? or all of them in pairs?

Comment: @SeanSdahl I have two date columns in my dateframe name 'DOB' and 'DisDt' . i need to find the difference between these two dates for all rows in the date frame

Comment: 01/01/2008
12-04-2004
01/06/1978
01/01/74
12-04-1968 \n are these in the csv file like this?

Comment: @SeanSdahl yes it is like  that, unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
with open ("file.csv", "r", newline='') as file:
    dates = []    
    for line in file:
        line.replace("/","-")
        dates.append(line)
```

Then you should get a list of items that are all separated by "-"